# Replace color in image measured by Euclidean distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy

This script replaces the red hair in image to black color (replace one color to another)

---

#### Three major parts in this script

- Not just replace color red to black, I hope the output image looks natural, so I will replace the color **close to** red to black. This "close" is measured by Euclidean distance.
- And not just replace by black color, user can modify the red color's `r, g, b` value separately, like add more green.
- Choose the area to be changed, rather than change the whole picture

---

#### Suggestions I am looking for:

- I did some NumPy practice before, so any suggestions about NumPy are welcome.
- I think the code to replace target area is not so elegant, I am not quite sure about this part:

  ```
  (c1, r1), (c2, r2) = area
  for i in range(r1, r2+1):
      l, r = i*h+c1, i*h+c2+1
      data[l:r,:k][D[l:r]] = modification(data[l:r,:k][D[l:r]])
  ```

---

#### Full code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

def replace_corlor(image, original_corlor, modification, area=None, distance=1000, output="new_test.jpg"):
    print("[*] START Replace Color")
    img = Image.open(image)
    data = np.asarray(img, dtype="int32")
    w,h,k = data.shape
    data = np.reshape(data, (w*h,k))
    distMatrix = cdist(data, np.array([original_corlor]))
    D = distMatrix<=distance
    D = np.reshape(D,w*h)
    if area is None:
        data[:,:k][D] = modification(data[:,:k][D])
    else:
        (c1, r1), (c2, r2) = area
        for i in range(r1, r2+1):
            l, r = i*h+c1, i*h+c2+1
            data[l:r,:k][D[l:r]] = modification(data[l:r,:k][D[l:r]])
    data = np.reshape(data, (w,h,k))
    img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(np.clip(data, 0, 255), dtype="uint8"), "RGB")
    img.save(output)
    print("[*] DONE Replace Color")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def modification(color):
        return color * [2,0,0]
        # return [255,0,0]
    replace_corlor("test.jpg",(36,35,30),modification, ((0,0),(400,100)))
```

Comment: I have no comments on your code, your Python is better than mine. :) But for color modification you could use the distance to the `original_color` value. The larger this distance (and the closer the distance is to the `distance` threshold), the less you modify the color. This way, you will get a smoother transition at the edges of the red region.

Comment: Couple of points, firstly, it appears that the modification function only works if it operates on vectors, rather than a single pixel, as you're passing that function the whole image at once. In some ways, it is doing most of the work. Secondly, There's a typo in the variable name original_corlor, nothing major, just confused me for a second. I find the contents of the else clause very confusing, partly because of very short variable names.

Comment: @gbartonowen sorry I don't get what you mean "it operates on vectors, rather than a single pixel", there is a `area` in parameters, if you wanna just change one pixel, for example the first pixel, just set area=((0,0),(1,1)), and about the typo, you are totally right

Comment: @Aries_is_there The modification function takes a 3D array of pixels, rather than a single pixel, which means you must formulate the function as numpy compatible operators. In this case it works fine but it looks like a _happens to work_ rather than _is meant to work like this_

Answer (score 2):

Nice code.
Let's look at the function signatures.
As gbartonowen noted, two typos on `corlor` for `color`.
The keyword defaults are lovely,
thank you for appropriately dealing with a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), and defaulting the filespec.
Lots of keywords will lead to a somewhat long signature, though, as reported by [`$ flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/):

```
E501 line too long (106 > 79 characters)
```

Recommend you always run such a linter before sharing code.
And heed the linter's advice.
In the same vein we see things like [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) wants spaces in the `w, h, k` assignment,
or `(w * h, k)` expression.
And, this being python rather than java,
[snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) identifiers of `d` and `dist_matrix` would be much more appropriate.
Python convention says the Gentle Reader should expect `D` to be a class.
(Yes, I know this clashes with conventions of the mathematical community,
something had to give. Ok, on to more substantive comments.)

An identifier of `data` is always on the vague side,
it's a bit like naming your variable `the_thing`.
Yes, it's accurate, but often it could be a little more informative.
Consider a rename along these lines:

```
    img = np.asarray(Image.open(image), dtype='int32')
```

(Hmmm, as I look at that, maybe we'd like identifiers of `in_file` and `out_file`?)

The `cdist()` call, which defaults to Euclidean, is pretty interesting,
since RGB is not a [perceptually uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) color scheme.
Consider mapping to [Lab*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) colorspace and using that for comparisons.

It is slightly tricky for a naive caller to correctly pass in `area`,
so it warrants mention in the docstring you're going to write,
or *at least* in a comment.
Similarly for the `modification` signature.
Consider [raising an error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) if `c1 < c2` or `r1 < r2` does not hold.

The `l, r` identifiers are well chosen,
and I eventually puzzled out their meaning,
but I wouldn't mind a comment mentioning "left, right",
as I kept thinking in terms of "row".
I also wouldn't mind seeing comments explaining the need for each `reshape()`.

If speed is a concern, then figuring out how to get `modification()`
to broadcast values to a sub-rectangle would be the thing to focus on.

The saturating aspect of `[2, 0, 0]` is slightly surprising,
please comment on it, and how it deliberately interacts with `clip()`.
Also, the list is not pythonic, this should definitely be the tuple `(2, 0, 0)`.
A more descriptive name, perhaps `red_modification`, would be appropriate.

Protecting `def modification` so `import` won't see it
*kind of* make sense, but is a little weird.
You don't want that example to be part of your public API, that's fine.
But consider using `def _modification` in the usual way,
so the `__main__` clause is just a one-liner.

Well, OK, two lines, as the magic tuple `(36, 35, 30)`
needs a name like `dark_gray`.

Looks good, ship it!